# A sufficient condition for $i_*: \pi_{1} (\partial M) \rightarrow \pi_{1} (M)$ to be a surjection

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

I am trying to prove the following theorem,
Given a smooth manifold $M$ which has only one end and each of whose finite coverings have only one end, the inclusion map $i: \partial M \rightarrow M$ induces a surjection $i_*: \pi_{1} (\partial M) \rightarrow \pi_{1} (M)$.

There is another theorem, can be found in [a paper by Gilles Carron and Emmanual Pedon](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0303348.pdf), Proposition 5.2, page 27, which uses almost the same hypothesis to show that $H^1_0(M,\mathbb{Z})=\left\{0\right\}$. I was trying to construct a non-zero element in $H^1_0(M,\mathbb{Z})$ starting from an element in $\pi_1(M)-\pi_1 (\partial M)$ but I am unable to. Could anyone please tell me if this line of thought appropriate or propose another method?

Comment: You could try to prove that the image $i^*(\pi_1(\delta M))$ is a normal subgroup. (It looks to me true) and then copy the proof in the article.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to prove is simply false. (I assume that by "end" you mean an end in the sense of Freudenthal as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)).) Take a closed 4-manifold $N$ with simple infinite fundamental group (such things exist). Let $M$ be obtained from $N$ by removing one point and then an open ball. The manifold $M$  has $\pi_1(M)\cong \pi_1(N)$, one boundary component which is the 3-sphere and one end. Then $M$ has no nontrivial finite (connected) covers (since $\pi_1(M)$ is simple and infinite). At the same time, $1=\pi_1(\partial M)\to \pi_1(M)$ is definitely not onto.

I strongly suspect that you have in mind more restrictions on the manifold $M$ and maybe by an "end" you mean something very nonstandard. If this is the case, you should spell it out.